# LibGit2Sharp takes forever to stage

Tags: libgit2sharp

Using Lib2GitSharp.  I know shallow clone is not supported, but I still need to clone a large repo, make some changes, stage and check it in.  It's taking almost an hour to stage the changes.  I've tried a couple of ways.  You can see I've tried Commands.Stage(repo, "*") as well as looping through the status.  Is there a faster way?

```
    public void StageChanges(string clonePath)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Staging repo");
            Repository repo = new Repository(clonePath);

            // Commands.Stage(repo, "*");
            var status = repo.RetrieveStatus();
            if (status.Modified.Any())
            {
                foreach (var file in status.Modified)
                {
                    Commands.Stage(repo, file.FilePath);
                }
            }

            _logger.LogInformation($"Staged repo");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, $"Error staging file path {clonePath}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many files are you attempting to stage? How long does each operation take (e.g. how long does the `RetrieveStatus()` command take to run, how long does it take to stage a single file?

Comment: Well, I ran it locally and it took 16 seconds to retrieve the status.  Staged 4 files.  The repo is 890 GB.  In Azure, it is taking almost an hour.  Not sure how many files though.   This is on an S1 server.

Comment: I'll have to deploy it with logging to know for sure how long each piece is taking, how many files, etc